# Should I be concerned about respiratory hazard from leftover/lurking silica sand from abrasive blasting (sandblasting)?

Tags: cleaning, ventilation, sanding

I know the media itself is a respiratory hazard while blasting (I'm told the silica sand itself breaks apart from the blasting and becomes dust-like). The area will be ventilated. However, I worry about whether this hazard will remain or spread, and for how long.  Would cleaning the area with large amounts of water help mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silica becomes a hazard with long term exposure.  Wear a mask, face shield and gloves while blasting.  Clean up and you are fine afterwards.  A small amount of exposure will not affect the vast majority of people.  If you have asthma you might want to be a little more aggressive on the clean up.